# $this->request->getData(); no recupera el data

Tags: jquery, ajax, data, cakephp-3.x

Me estoy volviendo loco con el response de AJAX quiero pasar una variable por ajax y recuperarla con cakephp.

La variable a recuperar es "**opcion**"

**jQuery + AJAX:**

```
$(document).on("click", "#modificar-foto-cuenta", function() {          
                var opcion = $(this).attr("id").valueOf();              
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Users/home/",
                        data: "opcion = " + opcion,
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: function (response) { console.log(response); },
                    error: function () { alert('error'); }
                    });                 
                $('.modalHome').show();         
        });
```

**Controlador:**

```
public function home() {
       if($this->request->is('post')) {         
         $data = $this->request->getData();  
         $this->set([
                     'data' => $data,
                     '_serialize' => 'data'
                   ]);        
       }
```

**Vista:**

```
if(isset($data->opcion)) {
    $opcion = $data->opcion;
  }
```

Pues no hay manera dice que no reconoce **data** y se queda tan pancho.

Se que el problema esta en el controlador, porque el ajax me devuelve success, osea que ajax procesa bien el post, pero por algún razón que desconozco el controlador no detecta el post, he probado a cambiar **post** a **ajax** con idéntico resultado.

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

**EDITO:**

He realizado algunos cambios:

**jQuery + AJAX:**

```
$(document).on("click", "#modificar-foto-cuenta", function() {
            var opcion = $(this).attr("id").valueOf();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Users/home/",
                data: { opcion: opcion },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data) { console.log(data); },
                error: function (data) { console.log(data); alert('error no ajax'); }
            });
            $('.modalHome').show();
        });
```

**Controlador:**

```
public function home() {
       if($this->request->is('post')) {
         $data = $this->request->getData();         
         $this->set('data', $data);
       }
     }
```

**Vista:**

```
<div class="modalHome">
<?php
     $paso = $data['opcion'];
     echo $this->element('modalHome', ['opcion' => $paso ]);
?>
```

**modalHome**

```
<?php
     echo $opcion;
?>
```

Me da el siguiente error:

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: data [APP/Template/Users/home.ctp,
>   line 50]

La linea 50 es ---> `$paso = $data['opcion'];`

Pero lo más curioso de todo es que el **console.log(data);** si me devuelve el valor:

```
<div class="modalHome">
modificar-foto-cuenta</div>
```

Comment: No estoy seguro que tu AJAX este correcto hace mucho que no utilizo esta sintaxis, pero según yo los parámetros deben de ir de esta formal.    data: "opcion:" +  opcion en lugar de esta:    data: "opcion = " + opcion. Te dice que la variable no existe efectivamente porque no esta reconocida en el parámetro. Inclusive puedes ver los headers de la petición y lo notaras.  Si te sirve te puedo decir una forma de hacerlo con axios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sola cambia tu línea de código del data en tu `Ajax`, la estás enviando mal, déjala de la siguiente manera:

```
....
data: {opcion: opcion},
....
```

La sintaxis de JSON en Javascript nos indica que debemos usar el formato:

```
{name:"Jhon"}
```

Donde "name" es el nombre de tu variable y "Jhon" el contenido de ésta.

Puedes ver más [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp).

Comment: He realizado cambios en el código, pero me sigue sin devolver el valor, pero el  `console.log(data);` si me devuelve el valor.

Comment: Te devuelve el valor en el Success? Si es así entonces el error ahora lo tenemos en la vista, ¿Por qué no guardas la variable $data en la sesión?
Cambia `$this->set('data', $data);` por `$session->write('data', $data);` y en tu vista cambia `$paso = $data['opcion'];` por `$paso = $session->read('data');` y dinos si funciona.

Comment: Me da error `Internal Server Error [500]` probé también con $session = `$this->request->getSession();
        $session->write('data', $data); $paso = $session->read('data');` pero da el mismo error

Comment: Error 500 significa que algo salió mal en tu controlador, ¿que te muestra en la cosola?

Comment: Voy abrir una nueva pregunta, ya que el problema que tengo ahora es con la vista y el controlador.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia tu petición Ajax por esto.

```js
  let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
  
  axios.get(url).then(
    res=>{
       $('#p').html(JSON.stringify(res.data));
    },
    err => {
      $('#p').html(err);
    }

  );
  
  /* No encontre una pagina que me dejara hacer 
     directamente peticiones post pero te dejo 
     la sintaxis
  
  
  axios.post(
  url,
  {
    // parametros
    opcion: $('#input').val(),
    otro: "este es un ejeplo"
  }
  ).then(
    res=>{
       $('#p').html(JSON.stringify(res.data));
    },
    err => {
      $('#p').html(err);
    }

  );
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" name="var" value="1" id="input"/>

<div id="p">a</div>
```

Comment: No conozco axios, así que prefiero no liarme con eso.