# La vista no esta mostrando los parametros pasados por el controlador

Tags: variables, data, cakephp-3.x

Relacionado con esta pregunta --->> [$this->request->getData(); no recupera el data](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/226184/this-request-getdata-no-recupera-el-data)

No se porque en la vista no se esta mostrando la variable **$opcion**, en cambio en el **success** si la esta mostrando:

```
<div class="modalHome">
modificar-foto-cuenta</div>
```

**jQuery + AJAX:**

```
$(document).on("click", "#modificar-foto-cuenta", function() {          
                var opcion = $(this).attr("id").valueOf();              
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Users/home/",
                        data: "opcion = " + opcion,
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: function (response) {           console.log(response); },
                    error: function () { alert('error'); }
                    });                 
                $('.modalHome').show();         
        });
```

**Controlador:**

```
  public function home() {
        if($this->request->is('post')) {
          $data = $this->request->getData();
          $opcion = $data['opcion'];

        /*$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
          $session->write('opcion', $opcion);
          $opcion = $session->read('opcion');*/

          $this->set('opcion', $opcion);
        }
        else {
          $this->set('opcion', 'No pasa');
        }
     }
```

**Vista:**

```
<div class="modalHome">
   <?php echo $opcion; ?>
</div>
```

He probado con **session**, pero con idéntico resultado

Answer (score 1):

Debes guardar tu variable en la sesión para que sea accesible desde cualquier parte de PHP, de este modo:

```
public function home() {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
      $data = $this->request->getData();
      $opcion = $data['opcion'];

      $this->Session->write('opcion', $opcion);
      //o:
      Session::write('opcion', $opcion)
    }
    else {
      $this->set('opcion', 'No pasa');
    }
 }
```

Comment: No funciona, pero por lo que leo eso añade a un elemento html contenido, como por ejemplo un parrafo a un elemento p.

Comment: ¿Cuál fue el error? ¿Salió algo en la consola? ¿Salió algo en tu HTML?

Comment: Se me corto lo que estaba comentado, vuelvo a empezar: Lo he probado y no funciona. pero por lo que leo append añade a un elemento HTML contenido, como por ejemplo un parrafo a un elemento **p**. Pero eso no es lo que busco, no me sirve de nada que me devuelva el contenido directamente en la vista.

Comment: Yo necesito guardarlo en una variable PHP. Ya que en realidad no es un click, son varios clicks en diferentes partes y necesito controlar ese evento ¿Donde esta el usuario haciendo click?  De hay la necesidad de la variable para luego procesarla con un switch que dependiendo donde el usuario haya hecho click la variable tomada un valor u otro y se generada un formulario u otro, que es la finalidad final de todo esto.

Comment: No quiero meter tanta información aquí para no volver el código más complicado y tampoco es importante para lo que busco que es que me devuelva una variable en PHP (**opcion**). Haciendo lo que me dices la consola devuelve un div vació y el HTML vació.

Comment: Ahora entiendo, lo que pasa que en tu pregunta no especificas que la quieres guardar en PHP, solo dices que no se mostró en la vista. Lo que te recomiendo es que en tu controlador guardes la variable en la sesión, de esta forma puedes acceder desde cualquier parte de PHP a tu variable. Edito mi respuesta.

Comment: Lo hacía a efectos prácticos, para ver que es lo que me estaba devolviendo la variable y para que se entendiese mejor lo que preguntaba, luego esa variable la tengo que pasar a un element de CakePHP.

Comment: ¿Amigo entonces que es lo que quieres?

Comment: Pues me da error **500** utilizando session: 'setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader()
​
state: function state()
​
status: 500
​
statusCode: function statusCode()
​
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
​
then: function then()'

Comment: Ese error es de Json y significa que lago salió mal en tu controlador, verifica en la consola del navegador que error arrojó el Controller (en Chrome en la pestaña Network).

Comment: "que error arrojó el Controller (en Chrome en la pestaña Network)." 
Ya te lo puse en el comentario anterior